# Bluehost's mail server seems not be sending my emails from Swiftmailer

Tags: php, laravel, swiftmailer

I've a laravel app nad I've been testing it with gmail smtp server and It was working in my system's localhost but then I deployed it on server (blue host) and change the configuration and still the app thinks that is sending emails and it's not giving me errors but no email is delivered to corresponding email addresses....

Here's my mail.php in app folder:

```
 return array(
'driver' => 'smtp',
'host' => 'mail.mash-up.fi',
'port' => 26,
'from' => array('address' => 'registration@mash-up.fi', 'name' => 'Admin'),
'encryption' => 'tls',
'username' => '************',
'password' => '******',
'sendmail' => '/usr/bin/sendmail -bs',
'pretend' => false,
);
```

where I'm doing wrong?

any help is appreciated

Comment: if swiftmailer isn't complaining, then it's probably working fine. check the mail server logs to see what happens after swiftmailer hands over the email. remember... swiftmailer isn't dropipng the email into the recipients mail server, it's simply handing over the email to a server which does the actual delivery. once that handoff is completed, swiftmailer is done and can report success. if the sending or receiving server then decide to dump the email on the floor, that's not swiftmailer's problem.

Comment: To add to Marc's comment: your mail is being submitted to the outgoing server just fine, the outgoing server is not delivering it. Talk to your host.

Comment: @MarcB : yeah I know what you're talking about, I'm not saying It's on swiftmailer, I simply requested a solution and It seems It's outta my hand too, I'll talk with the server to see what's going on....

thanks to both of you (@Sammitch)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are using the BH DNS(ns1.bluehost...), then check to see that the $from address is an existing email in your BH account.
(go to your CP /domain manager and use whois info to find that out.)
or.....
maybe, you migrated the source code, but did you transfer your domain name to BH, or is it pointing to BH servers (DNS)
In that case your site is not using the BH mail servers.
example :your site content could be on BH, but if it is registered somewhere else and the DNS is not ns1.bluehost.com..etc, then your domain might be using url forwarding or framing (to bring visitors to the BH location). but your mail functions may be handled by the registrar's

hope this is not too confusing
it is also helpfull if you post your domain name here and others can help figure out as well.

Answer (score 2):

Please try to check the spam folder of where your sending to. If there is nothing, make sure your "from" is truly your bluehost email account your using to send the email. If the actual sender doesn't match the "from" of the e-mail many mail clients will ignore it entirely (like hotmail), but gmail will put it in the spam folder with a warning.

The host should be your bluehost box I think. In fact on cpanel, go to email, where you create accounts. Then click on "More", select "Configure Email Client", scroll down. You will see the host name, and port.

TTL/SSL would likely need port 465, I am guessing (I use the latter, not the former like you).

Answer (score 0):

Open up the laravel.logs file inside of storage > logs. It should help give you some idea of what the problem might be.